# React-select: arrow navigation unavailable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a React Select instance that works well. However, because I have made a custom option component, I can't navigate through options with keyboard arrows.

Here is my code:

```js
    const StyledOption = ({ children, onSelect, ...props }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {children}
          <button onClick={() => null}>include</button>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const Autocomplete = ({options}) => {
      return (
          <Select
            options={options}
            components={{Option: ({ children, ...props }) => ( <StyledOption {...{ children, onSelect, ...props }}/>)}}
          />
         )};
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Tell us more about your code, pls.

Comment: SO wouldn't let me write more code. But basically, there is nothing more to check. It's just a select with a custom component to render every option. Options are correctly displayed with my custom style, but arrow navigation doesn't work anymore. I would like to fix this. I've tried to add a forwardRef() wrapper around the StyledOption function, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: This may help, https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#mouse-and-pointer-events